# How to get TimeStampPath in Google Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't find any information whether it's possible or not to get the timestamp of every touchpoint into the path? (I use `RGA library` in r:  `get_mcf()` to get conversion paths)

Thanks in advance for any information

Comment: The closest you will get within the MCF is nthDay or timeLagInDaysHistogram, however I doubt this is what you are looking for.